# Progress OpenEdge installation in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, progress-4gl

Is it possible to install OpenEdge 11 (Progress 4GL) Software on the Ubuntu operating system?

If so, please explain how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Download your Linux distribution from Progress. If you want a demo license you need to contact them. Make sure you download a 64-bit and not a 32-bit tar file (unless you happen to run a 32-bit machine).

Put the tar file on your Progress system. Let's say you have it in your home directory:

```
/home/user/PROGRESSFILENAME.tar
```

Extract it:

```
cd /home/user
tar xvf PROGRESSFILENAME.tar
```

It will create a directory named

```
proinst
```

Change directory to another destination and create a temporary directory there. For example:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir proinst116
cd proinst116
```

Now run the installationscript (named "proinst" in the directory "proinst"):

```
/home/user/proinst/proinst
```

And your up and running:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                              Welcome                              |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                                   |
 |         WELCOME TO THE OPENEDGE INSTALLATION UTILITY              |
 |                                                                   |
 | Ensure that you have your completed "Preinstallation Checklist    |
 | for Unix" handy to consult. This information will facilitate your |
 | installation and ensure your choices are accurately recorded.     |
 |                                                                   |
 |     Copyright (c) 1984-2015 Progress Software Corporation         |
 |         and/or one of its subsidiaries or affiliates.             |
 |                     All Rights Reserved.                          |
 |                                                                   |
 |                                                                   |
 |                            [Enter=OK]                             |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now you will need to insert license keys, company name etc.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     Product Configuration Data                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                [Enter=Additional]    |
| Company Name: ______________________________   [Ctrl-E=Done]         |
| Serial Number: _________                       [CTRL-T=Quit]         |
| Control Number: _____  _____  _____            [CTRL-N=Release Notes]|
|                                                [CTRL-V=View]         |
|                                                [TAB=Next Field]      |
|                                                [CTRL-P=Help]         |
|                                                [CTRL-A=Addendum File]|
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Once that is done, press Ctrl-E to continue and you will have to enter some more information like:

- Destination directory
- Working directory
- Default Codepage
- Default language
- Default date and number formats
- etc.

Once that's done your installation will be ready to start. Takes about a minute or so on a modern box.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

according to this:
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-versions-of-Linux-are-supported-by-OpenEdge-11

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64-bit (certified for OE11.3.2 and higher)

official documentation (install guide) is here:
http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge116/openedge116/#page/gsins/committing-your-installation-choices.html#